# Prove that $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How to prove that $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}=1$?

I know that $x$ grows much faster to infinity then $\ln(x)$, therefore the limit equivalent to $e^0 = 1$

but that's not a rigorous proof.

Comment: Are you asking how to prove that $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{\log (x)}{x}\right)=0$?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially my question.

Comment: Do you know how to prove $$\lim_{y\to+\infty} \frac{y}{e^y} = 0\,?$$

Comment: How are you defining $\log$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I understand the "new" limit. I also know how to prove it by LHopital's Rule. But is there a more fundamental way?

Comment: Again, $e^y$ "grows" faster than $y$.

Comment: You could also note that $$\exp\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right) = x^{1/x},$$ and for $n \leqslant x < n+1$, you have $n^{1/(n+1)} < x^{1/x} < (n+1)^{1/n}$. Then you can get $n^{1/n} \to 1$ from an expansion $$n = (1+\delta_n)^n = 1 + n\delta_n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\delta_n^2 + \dotsc \implies \delta_n < \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}.$$ Then use that and the bounds for $x^{1/x}$ above to conclude.

Comment: I guess LHopital's Rule really makes life much easier :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$

by [L Hopital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule)

Comment: Thank you. Is there an alternative for LHopital's Rule?

Comment: I guess you could convert the limit to $$\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{e^y}$$. Then, using the Taylor' series expansion of $e^y$ about 0, this limit is $$\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y^{-1}}{y^{-2}+y^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{y}{6}+...}=0$$.

Answer (score 3):

Take the function inside $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}$ and let $y$ be that function,

$$y = e^\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$

Apply logarithm to both sides,

$$\ln(y) = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$

Applying the limits,

$$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(y) = \lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$

Since in $\dfrac{ln(x)}{x}$, as $x\to \infty$, both numerator and denominator goes to infinity (one of the requirement before we can apply L'Hospital Rule), we can take the L'Hospital Rule,

$$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(y) = \lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{1}$$

$$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(y) = \lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x} = 0$$

Now we get rid of the log,

$$e^{\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(y)} = e^{\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}} = e^0$$

$$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} y = 1$$

Finishing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the exponential function $e^x$ increases more faster then every $x^a$ , $a \in \mathbb R$. Since ln(x) is strict monotone increasingly this relation still holds for $ln(e^x)$ and $ln(x^a)$ for $a=1$ we know now that $x$ incrases more faster then $ln(x)$ we obtain:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\frac{ln(x)}{x}}=e^{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ln(x)}{x} }=e^0=1 $